# If I have a public load balancer, how does direct service-to-service communication get load balanced?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

```
                                  |--> service1:8081 --> pod1-a, pod1-b, pod1-c
   UI -> load balancer -> ingress (mydomain.com)
                                  |--> service2:8082 --> pod2-a, pod2-b, pod2-c
```

So from `service1`, I could call `service2` directly with `http://service2:8082`, but since this is not being done through the UI -> load balancer, how does this get load balanced? Should I not call `service2` directly, and call it through `mydomain.com/service2` instead so it would have to go through the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are by-passing the ingress, meaning directly calling `http://service2:8082` from `service1`, Kubernetes would pick a random backend based on the default [`Proxy-mode: iptables`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables).

You can tweak this a bit more if you are using something like [ipvs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs). For example, set up round robin.

You can also use the old [`Proxy-mode: userspace`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-userspace) if you'd like round robin only.

All these options are configurable using the [`-proxy-mode ProxyMode`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/) flag on the kube-proxy.

Comment: So it seems like I have a choice. Now what if I have additional functionality on my Ingress e.g. some sort of authentication attached to it? In that case, I should probably call it through mydomain.com/service2 so the authentication works, yes?

Comment: Yes. Additional functionality that you could implement with something like nginx or Traefik.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a service from another service will hit the iptable routes on the node and pick service endpoint to route traffic to. This will be faster.

If you call it through mydomain.com/service2, then the flow passes through additional L7 ingress and will be comparatively slow.